# iguanaTex error about Latex

Tags: iguanatex

everyone,

I have installed IguanaTex in powerpoint on a 64-bit Windows10 PC. I have also installed TexLive. IguanaTex cannot find pdfLatex and returns error when running:  "pdflatex"-shell-escape-interaction=batchmode"iguanatex_tmp.tex". Would anyone help with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered with the same problem like you. After severl failure and try, I fixed this problem.

1. Click the label "IguanaTex" in Powerpoint
2. Click "Main Settings" in the Setting section.
3. In the prompt window, you will see a list of path to fill in at the bottom, and you need to insert the path of where the file "pdfLaTeX.exe" exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the guide

> LaTeX can be downloaded from MiKTeX or TeX Live
>   **It is important you keep to just one OR the other**
>
> ◾(Optional but recommended): GhostScript and ImageMagick, required to
>   use the optional LaTeX to PDF to PNG conversion.
>   ◾(Optional but
>   recommended): TeX2img, used for vector graphics output
>
> For compatibility ensure GhostScript is version 9.14 or later

### How to test if the components will work together

Start a system command prompt (on windows 10 that's easily done from the search box by typing `cmd` and enter.

check each of the following

```
prompt> Where /r \ pdfLaTeX
prompt> Where $path:pdflatex
```

both of them should report EXACTLY the same info. That is the location of pdfLaTeX in EITHER a MiKTeX or TexLive directory. If there is more than one answer for each or one is not the same as the other you need to clear up that issue first (see below)

Similarly if you installed GhostScript you need matching results for

```
prompt> Where /r \ gs*c.exe
prompt> Where $path:gs*c.exe
```

However in this case there may be two, four (or even more replies) what you are checking for is that at least one from each set MATCH EXACTLY

and for ImageMagick you are testing for convert

```
prompt> Where /r \ convert
prompt> Where $path:convert
```

### What to fix

If the first response is `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` then the application was not found and is most likely not installed.

If the second response is `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` then the application is not correctly installed such that it can be run by another application.

### How to fix

In the first case review the applications documentation and amend the search name if necessary.

In the second case you need to add the folder name prior to the application to your system path. (Since this is system/user dependant I will simply suggest you web search "Add folder to path" and look for results appropriate for your system) 
NOTE that the folder needs to include the full path so for example if the first response was

```
C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\MiKTeX\bin\pdfLaTeX.exe
```

Then the item to add to path is ( without the \ )

```
C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\MiKTeX\bin
```

Similarly if using TeX Live it may be `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32`

Once the above settings are correct a command such as

`pdfLaTeX -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode iguanatex_tmp.tex`

should work

Comment: Thank you for the answer.